# Symfony and doctrine searchable sfDoctrinePager (symfony 1.4)

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

Can someone help me on paginating results with sfDoctrinePager?

```
$articlesResults = Doctrine::getTable('Article')
                                            ->getTemplate('Doctrine_Template_I18n')
                                            ->getPlugin()
                                            ->getTable()
                                            ->getGenerator('Doctrine_Search')
                                            ->search($searchTerm);
```

This is the code I use to get the search results, this works fine, but I'm stuck on paginating them with sfDoctrinePager.
Tnx for the help.

Comment: nobody paginates there results?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? Using the sfDoctrinePager class? I can provide an example of using it if that's where you're having problems :-)

Comment: I want to combine sfDoctrinePager and the Searchable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/searching/en

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('NewsItem i');

$q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Article')
    ->search('test', $q);

$newsItems = $q->execute();
```

Would return NewsItem objects

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchResults = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table')->search($query);

foreach($searchResults as $result)
  $ids[] = $result['id'];

$pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Editeur', 10);
$pager->setQuery(Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table')->findSearchQuery($ids));
$pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$pager->init();

$this->pager = $pager;
```